# How to expose custom jar in lib folder of java web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty

I have an existing jetty application that i need to modify. Basically i just need one access point that can handle POST requests. I have access to the WEB-INF directory of the project. There i have web.xml file and a lib folder. As i understand from jetty documentation jars under lib will be loaded automatically. Is it possible to add a custom jar under lib folder and the somehow configure web.xml so that my jar will handle HTTP requests from a certain URL? If so how would i start with that?

Comment: A jar file doesn't handle requests. A servlet does. Register the servlet as explained in the servlet specifications and plenty of tutorials (i.e. using a servlet declaration in web.xml, or by annotating your servlet with WebServlet), and you'll have another servlet. Whether its class is in one jar or another doesn't matter, as long as the jar is in the webapp classpath, i.e. under WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a jar with your Servlet class inside (a class that extends HttpServlet) and add the servlet declaration inside the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>A_Name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.new.ServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>A_Name</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/the/path/you/want</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```